# replace key with new array values

Tags: php

```
$arrayfirst = 

    Array
    (
        [0] => 23:00-08:00
        [1] => 23:00-08:00
        [2] => 23:00-08:00
        [3] => 23:00-08:00
        [4] => 23:00-08:00
        [5] => 00:00-00:00
        [6] => 00:00-00:00
    )
```

I want to replace the keys [0][1][2][3][4][5][6]

with the values of

```
$arraysecond = 

    Array
    (
        [0] => Monday
        [1] => Tuesday
        [2] => Wedneday
        [3] => Thursday
        [4] => Friday
        [5] => Saturday
        [6] => Sunday
    )
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_combine` -

```
$new = array_combine($arraysecond, $arrayfirst);
```

The values of `$arraysecond` will be the keys of `$arrayfirst`.

[array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayfirst = array(
        0 => '23:00-08:00',
        1 => '23:00-08:00',
        2 => '23:00-08:00',
        3 => '23:00-08:00',
        4 => '23:00-08:00',
        5 => '00:00-00:00',
        6 => '00:00-00:00',
    );

    $arraysecond = array(
        0 => 'Monday',
        1 => 'Tuesday',
        2 => 'Wedneday',
        3 => 'Thursday',
        4 => 'Friday',
        5 => 'Saturday',
        6 => 'Sunday',
    );

    $new = array_combine($arraysecond, $arrayfirst);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($new);
    echo '</pre>';
```

OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [Monday] => 23:00-08:00
    [Tuesday] => 23:00-08:00
    [Wedneday] => 23:00-08:00
    [Thursday] => 23:00-08:00
    [Friday] => 23:00-08:00
    [Saturday] => 00:00-00:00
    [Sunday] => 00:00-00:00
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using:

```
$result = array_combine($arraysecond, $arrayfirst);
```

Comment: yet somebody answered your question before you solved it. might wanna give credit.

Comment: yes, noticed. will sure do.